# Tell the module requirements in a particular directory (package)

Tags: python, dependencies, requirements.txt

In my office we have a quite complex directory structure when it comes to our code.

One of the things we have is a `libs` module to drop "common" things used by other parts of our big application (or set of applications... that are all living under a common directory).

The code in that `libs/` directory requires certain packages installed in order for it to work. In said `libs/` directory we have a `requirements.txt` file that *supposedly* lists the dependencies required for the things (things being Python code) in it to work. We have been filling that `requirements.txt` file pretty *manually*, tracking that "*if this .py file uses this module, we should add it to the requirements file*" so it's almost certain that by now we have forgotten adding some required modules.

Because of the complex structure we have (some parts use [`pipenv`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), some other have their own `requirements.txt`...) is very hard knowing whether a required module is going to end up installed or not.

So I would like to make sure that this `libs/` directory (cough, cough... *module* ) has all its dependencies listed in its `libs/requirements.txt`.

Is that possible? Ideally it'd be *"run this command passing `/libs/` as an argument, it'll scan the directory and tell you what packages are needed by the py(s) found in it"*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, python does not know whether its dependencies are satisfied until runtime. `requirements.txt` is just a helper file for pip and similar tools, and you have to update it manually.

That said, you could

- use the `os` module to recursively get a list of all `*.py` files in the folder
- parse each one of them for lines having the format `import aaa.bbb` or `from aaa import bbb`
- keep a set of the imports

However, even in that case, the name of the imported module *is not* the same as the name you need to pass to pip (eg, `import yaml` requires `pyyaml` in `requirements.txt`), but at least it could be a hint of what's missing.